# IP tables allow everything but restrict HTTP for only one IP

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm requested to manage a couple of web servers whenever my clients need something changed.

All I want is to do is restrict `HTTP` and `HTTPS` temporarily to myself while all other connections are open to everyone while I'm testing.

They don't have `iptables` managed but I have sudo access.

There's a lot of other services running which I don't want to interrupt. I don't want to disconnect to my ssh session either since I don't have console access to revert it.

If I run only these 2 commands, will it restrict only `HTTP` and `HTTPS` while other ports are working?

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --match multiport --dport 80,443 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 10.1.1.2 --match multiport --dport 80,443 -j ACCEPT
```

Edit: Changed the oder of the rules.

Comment: While you might get  a proper answer here, I think it would be worth setting up a VM and testing such things. Fiddling around `iptables` on a productive server and being unsure what the result of your `iptables` commands are is not a good idea.

Comment: I just wondered if the iptables firewall just follow the rules and nothing more? if that is the case, since there is no deny (except for ssh) in the above rules, it should let everything else. In simple words that was my question :)  Yea I should test it on a VM and figure that out

Comment: In this order it won't work. You should change the order as -I always adds to the beginning. This way you will have the DROP line first and nobody will be able to get there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tested it on a VM and it allows everything else. I'll update the question with the correct order. Can you reply as asnwer? I can accept your answer.

Comment: Too late :-). But I am glad I could have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Only whatever is in the `iptables --list` is processed, unless there is `DROP ALL` it allows everything else.

But if we are using `-I (Insert)` then order of the rules should be `Drop` first which means the `DROP` will be at the end while `ACCEPT` rules will be first processed.

```
[root@hostname ~]# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --match multiport --dport 80,443 -j DROP            
[root@hostname ~]# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 10.1.1.2 --match multiport --dport 80,443 -j ACCEPT
```

Now run `iptables --list`

```
[root@hostname ~]# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot    opt    source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp      --    10.1.1.2         anywhere            multiport dports http,https
DROP       tcp      --    anywhere         anywhere            multiport dports http,https
```